# SQL Server: How to make sqllogship.exe generate backup files with local instead of GMT files

Tags: backup, sql, logging, shipping

When SQL Server log shipping generates transaction logs through a command like

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\sqllogship.exe" -Backup 60CD93F9-CFC2-4A84-8B06-3AD8DEADBEEF -server DummyServer
```

The file that gets generated looks like

```
2010-08-20 15:02:29.12  The backup operation was successful. Primary Database: 'Dummy', Log Backup File: 'd:\test\Dummy_20100820220229.trn'
```

The date part of the file ("20100820220229") is in GMT time, not local time.

Any way to make it local time? That's better for correlating with logs etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No.  GMT is used in case you are log shipping between timezones.

Comment: Thanks mrdenny. I get that's a sensible default, but isn't that customizable? After all, log shipping doesn't rely on file names date/time to consume them, correct? thanks!

Comment: I don't believe that it is, as normally a person wouldn't ever look at the file names for any reason.  I believe that it does look at the date and time in the file as you can tell log shipping to delay import by X amount of time so it would need to know what time the files were created.